# Multi button not working in html webform, when click show button it is submitting

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, webforms

In the below HTML code we have two div, one is visible when we open the form, and another has to be visible when we click the "show" button and we have another button "submit" .

but, when I'm clicking the "show" button it is submitting the data. when I'm clicking the "Submit" button it is submitting the data.

All I need is when I click "show" it will show the data of  and when I click submit it will submit the data.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
              
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
            <base target="_top">
          
          </head>
          
          <body>
        <h1>Internal Order Form</h1>
        <form id="myform" >
            <div>
            <label for="Product1">Product01   :</label>
            <select id="Product1" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product1" required >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
        
              <label>Item Name01 :
              <input list="Item_Name1" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name1" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name1" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            
            
        
            Qty01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC1">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC1" name="KG_PC1">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate1" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size01   :
            <input type="text" name="Size1" id="Size1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No1" id="Order_No1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
            
           
            
           <br>
            <label for="Product2">Product02   :</label>
            <select id="Product2" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product2" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
            <label>Item Name02 :
              <input list="Item_Name2" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name2" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name2" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
            
        
        
            
            Qty02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_P">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC2" name="KG_PC2">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate2" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size02   :
            <input type="text" name="Size2" id="Size2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No2" id="Order_No2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           <br>
           </div>
           
        
           <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
           <label for="Product3">Product03   :</label>
            <select id="Product3" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product3" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
           
           <label>Item Name03 :
              <input list="Item_Name3" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name3" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name3" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            Qty03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC3" name="KG_PC3">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate3" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size03   :
            <input type="text" name="Size3" id="Size3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No3" id="Order_No3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
            
            <br>
        
            <label for="Product4">Product04   :</label>
            <select id="Product4" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product4" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
        
           <label>Item Name04 :
              <input list="Item_Name4" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name4" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name4" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            
        
            Qty04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC4" name="KG_PC4">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate4" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size04   :
            <input type="text" name="Size4" id="Size4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No4" id="Order_No4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           </div> 
          
         
           <button onclick="myFunction()">Show More</button>
           <button id="butn" >Submit</button>
           
        
            </form>
            <script>
           function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "visible";
          } 
        }
        
        
          document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
          function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resetForm)
                             .addNewItem(this);
          });
          
          function resetForm() {
            document.querySelector("#myform").reset();
          alert("Order Submited")
          }
         
        </script>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### just one word mistake!

---

**use *block* instead of *visible***

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
}
```

---

[wrong code photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1EV0.png)

---

[corrected code photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLzFa.png)

---

**corrected code below**

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
              
          <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
            <base target="_top">
          
          </head>
          
          <body>
        <h1>Internal Order Form</h1>
        <form id="myform" >
            <div>
            <label for="Product1">Product01   :</label>
            <select id="Product1" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product1" required >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
        
              <label>Item Name01 :
              <input list="Item_Name1" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name1" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name1" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            
            
        
            Qty01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC1">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC1" name="KG_PC1">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate1" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size01   :
            <input type="text" name="Size1" id="Size1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.01   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No1" id="Order_No1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
            
           
            
           <br>
            <label for="Product2">Product02   :</label>
            <select id="Product2" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product2" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
            <label>Item Name02 :
              <input list="Item_Name2" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name2" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name2" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
            
        
        
            
            Qty02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_P">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC2" name="KG_PC2">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate2" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size02   :
            <input type="text" name="Size2" id="Size2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.02   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No2" id="Order_No2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           <br>
           </div>
           
        
           <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
           <label for="Product3">Product03   :</label>
            <select id="Product3" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product3" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
           
           <label>Item Name03 :
              <input list="Item_Name3" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name3" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name3" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            Qty03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC3" name="KG_PC3">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate3" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size03   :
            <input type="text" name="Size3" id="Size3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.03   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No3" id="Order_No3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
            
            <br>
        
            <label for="Product4">Product04   :</label>
            <select id="Product4" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product4" >
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
            <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
            </select>
           
        
           <label>Item Name04 :
              <input list="Item_Name4" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name4" /></label>
              <datalist id="Item_Name4" >
              <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
                <?!= getVendors(); ?>
              </datalist>
        
            
        
            Qty04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Qty4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
            <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
            <select id="KG_PC4" name="KG_PC4">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
            <option value="KG">KG</option>
            <option value="PC">PC</option>
            </select>
        
            Rate04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Rate4" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 
        
           
            Size04   :
            <input type="text" name="Size4" id="Size4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           
              
            Order No.04   :
            <input type="Number" name="Order_No4" id="Order_No4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
           </div> 
          
         
           <button onclick="myFunction()">Show More</button>
           <button id="butn" >Submit</button>
           
        
            </form>
            <script>
           function myFunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
          if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
          } 
        }
        
        
          document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
          function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resetForm)
                             .addNewItem(this);
          });
          
          function resetForm() {
            document.querySelector("#myform").reset();
          alert("Order Submited")
          }
         
        </script>
         </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried with your changes but it is not working.same issue when im clicking show it is submitting the data.  you can check by run code snippet in your code when we are clicking show more it is asking produckt1 is required

Comment: Shukla that means submit code is running when you click to show more or submit (if you enter data in product1 and click show more both show more and submit are runnning )

Comment: @DurgaPrasad you can change style of link to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use link instead of button**

it will not submit data, but **onclick** it will call **myFuction(**)

**link** can be customized using **style** .

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");{
x.style.display = "block";
} 


<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">show more</a>
```

**customize link as you want using style**

---

**new code below as you want**

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
      
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5">
    <base target="_top">
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
<h1>Internal Order Form</h1>
<form id="myform" >
    <div>
    <label for="Product1">Product01   :</label>
    <select id="Product1" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product1" required >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
    </select>
   

      <label>Item Name01 :
      <input list="Item_Name1" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name1" /></label>
      <datalist id="Item_Name1" >
      <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </datalist>

    
    

    Qty01   :
    <input type="Number" name="Qty1" style="width: 100px;"  > 

    <label for="KG_PC1">KG/PC   :</label>
    <select id="KG_PC1" name="KG_PC1">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="KG">KG</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    </select>

    Rate01   :
    <input type="Number" name="Rate1" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 

   
    Size01   :
    <input type="text" name="Size1" id="Size1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   
      
    Order No.01   :
    <input type="Number" name="Order_No1" id="Order_No1" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
   
    
   <br>
    <label for="Product2">Product02   :</label>
    <select id="Product2" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product2" >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
    </select>
   
    <label>Item Name02 :
      <input list="Item_Name2" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name2" /></label>
      <datalist id="Item_Name2" >
      <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </datalist>
    


    
    Qty02   :
    <input type="Number" name="Qty2" style="width: 100px;"  > 

    <label for="KG_P">KG/PC   :</label>
    <select id="KG_PC2" name="KG_PC2">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="KG">KG</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    </select>

    Rate02   :
    <input type="Number" name="Rate2" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 

   
    Size02   :
    <input type="text" name="Size2" id="Size2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   
      
    Order No.02   :
    <input type="Number" name="Order_No2" id="Order_No2" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   <br>
   </div>
   

   <div id="myDIV" style="display: none;">
   <label for="Product3">Product03   :</label>
    <select id="Product3" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product3" >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
    </select>
   
   
   <label>Item Name03 :
      <input list="Item_Name3" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name3" /></label>
      <datalist id="Item_Name3" >
      <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </datalist>

    Qty03   :
    <input type="Number" name="Qty3" style="width: 100px;"  > 

    <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
    <select id="KG_PC3" name="KG_PC3">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="KG">KG</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    </select>

    Rate03   :
    <input type="Number" name="Rate3" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 

   
    Size03   :
    <input type="text" name="Size3" id="Size3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   
      
    Order No.03   :
    <input type="Number" name="Order_No3" id="Order_No3" style="width: 100px;"  > 
    
    <br>

    <label for="Product4">Product04   :</label>
    <select id="Product4" style="width: 100px;"  name="Product4" >
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="Cow_Milk_Items">Cow Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Buffalo_Milk_Items">Buffalo Milk Items</option>
    <option value="Dry_Items">Dry Items</option>
    </select>
   

   <label>Item Name04 :
      <input list="Item_Name4" style="width: 100px;" name="Item_Name4" /></label>
      <datalist id="Item_Name4" >
      <option value="" style="display:none;"></option> 
        <?!= getVendors(); ?>
      </datalist>

    

    Qty04   :
    <input type="Number" name="Qty4" style="width: 100px;"  > 

    <label for="KG_PC">KG/PC   :</label>
    <select id="KG_PC4" name="KG_PC4">
    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  
    <option value="KG">KG</option>
    <option value="PC">PC</option>
    </select>

    Rate04   :
    <input type="Number" name="Rate4" id="Number" style="width: 100px;"  > 

   
    Size04   :
    <input type="text" name="Size4" id="Size4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   
      
    Order No.04   :
    <input type="Number" name="Order_No4" id="Order_No4" style="width: 100px;"  > 
   </div> 
  
 
   <!-- before    <button onclick="myFunction()">Show More</button> -->
   <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">show more</a>
   <!--change style of link-->
   <button id="butn" >Submit</button>
   

    </form>
    <script>
   function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");{
    x.style.display = "block";
   } 
}


  document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", 
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(resetForm)
                     .addNewItem(this);
  });
  
  function resetForm() {
    document.querySelector("#myform").reset();
  alert("Order Submited")
  }
 
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: shukla ji Changed with your new code but when I click show more link it is redirecting to: https://n-njplwdndl5g5akv5tjjbq34zw5jcndoaqa2aimq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel#

Comment: @DurgaPrasad insure to give link **href="#"**.            eg. <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">show more</a>

Comment: @shukla ji, I copied your given code and paste it into the HTML code window, as you said again double-checked the code it is the same, I don't know where it is getting wrong.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad Have you tried **run snipped code**. here you can see all is perfect. try to run snipped code in stacks overflow window